# Is there an open connected set in $\mathbb{R^2}$ of finite Lebesgue measure, which has a non-empty intersection with any straight line?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is there an open connected set in $\mathbb{R^2}$ of finite Lebesgue measure, which has a non-empty intersection with any straight line ?

My Try :

The set of tuples $\Gamma = \{ (q_k,p_k) \}$ is a countable and dense subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$. Let $\{ r_1,r_2,... \}$ be an enumeration of $\Gamma$. For each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ Consider the open square $S_k$ having $r_k$ at its central point, with sides having length of $\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}}$. Hence , $m(S_k)=\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$. Now define $O=\bigcup^{\infty}_{k=1} S_k$, $$m(O) \leq \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} m(S_k) = \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{\epsilon}{2^k}=\epsilon$$
$O$ has a nonempty intersection with any line in $\mathbb{R^2}$ according to density of $\mathbb{Q^2}$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$ .

Seemingly, I have come up with an open set, dense in $\mathbb{R^2}$, and having as small measure as I want. Isn't it too much ?! That's why I decided to ask it here\, because I was asked to find an open set of "finite" measure.

Comment: I think it's possible to get such a result, but the argument you have given is false. There's no reason for your set not to avoid some lines.

Comment: I don't see why you say there is no reason ...

Comment: Can a line pass through irrationals "forever" ?

Comment: You've chosen an arbitrary enumeration. For all you know, it could be such that all those small balls will avoid a line, if only by a small margin. On the other hand: it's up to you to give a proof. You haven't given any, so I don't have much to refute.

Comment: Of course it can. Why wouldn't it? Try $y=x+\sqrt 2$.

Comment: I see what you mean , thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the set

$$A = \left\{(x, y) : |y| < \frac{1}{1 + x^2}\right\}$$

This has finite Lebesgue measure; its measure is twice the integral (over $\mathbb{R}$) of $1/(1 + x^2)$. Add to it a rotation of $A$ by an angle of $90^{\circ}$ around the origin, so that we have two double-sombrero shape regions. This new set satisfies the conditions posed.

Comment: You mean my answer is wrong ?

Comment: @Roozbeh-unity I don't see how your set is connected; furthermore, without knowing some things about the choice of enumeration of $\Bbb Q$, it may not hit every line.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff He said : add to it a rotation of $A$ by an angle of $90$ degrees ...

Comment: @Roozbeh-unity Missed that.

Answer (score 2):

A straight line has to intersect either the x-axis or the y-axis, so just take an open connected set covering the x and y axes with finite measure. For example for the x-axis, just take open boxes $B_n$ of length and height $\frac{1}{n}$, and make sure they each intersect a little bit, and similarly for the y-axis.

Comment: You mean my answer is wrong ?

Comment: Yours may not be connected.

Comment: Where exactly your boxes $B_n$ are located ? at each rational point on the x-axis ?

Comment: I edited my answer slightly....well for instance they can go from $0$ to $1$, and then from $1/2$ to $3/2$...etc. It doesn't really matter as long as they cover the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Let $\epsilon > 0$. Now let $U$ be the set of all $(x,y)$ so $|y| < \epsilon e^{-|x|}$.  Let $V$ be its reflection through the line $y = x$.  Put $G = U\cup V$. This can be made to have arbitrarily small measure and meets any line in the plane.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps more interesting is that you can have a connected open set of finite (and arbitrarily small) Lebesgue measure that intersects every straight line **segment** (of nonzero length).

Hint: every such segment intersects at least one of the lines $x = r$ and $y=r$ for rational $r$.